# No spatial ordering in 1+1D flat Minkowski spacetime?

Tags: special-relativity, reference-frames, inertial-frames, coordinate-systems, lorentz-symmetry

Consider 3 point masses in 1+1D flat Minkowski spacetime initially at rest w.r.t. each other and equally separated:

$A----B----C$

Suddenly, $A$ acquires a speed towards $C$ of $0.97c$. This corresponds to a Lorentz factor $\gamma(v) \simeq 4$.

From $A$'s viewpoint, distances to $B$ and $C$ are contracted by $4$:

$A-B-C$

No problem so far. From $B$'s viewpoint, distance to $C$ remains the same, but distance to $A$ is contracted by the same factor:

$A-B----C$

Still fine, just length contraction. Now comes the hard part. From $C$'s viewpoint, distance to $B$ is unaltered, but distance to $A$ is reduced by $4$:

$B--A--C$

So now $A$ lies *in between* $B$ and $C$.

Is this correct? Can observers disagree on *which* object is further away?

Comment: I am going to give an answer at a later time, but for now I am upvoting your question. This type of question gets asked all the time, but I have never seen it asked this well. You have taught me two things. First of all, the paradox that you have produced is a variation on the [ladder paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ladder_paradox). This paradox is one of the classics in special relativity. Your version is superior, because you have reduced the paradox to its absolute essence. Secondly, your notation is amazing. It describes the paradox very simply, where the usual description is wordy.

Comment: @vosov thanks, can't wait for your answer and how this relates to the barn-pole paradox.

Answer (score 5):

Let's start with some basic

- A pair of distinct events $P$ and $Q$ can be space-like separated $(\Delta \vec{x})^2 > (c \Delta t)^2$, time-like separated $(\Delta \vec{x})^2 < (c \Delta t)^2$, or light-like separated $(\Delta \vec{x})^2 = (c \Delta t)^2$ (and there are many variant names for this conditions including "null separated"). And these categories are invariant: they are the same to all inertial observers.
- Events that are **space-like separated** have no guaranteed temporal ordering, but do have a guaranteed spacial ordering. They also do not have zero spacial separation in any frame, but  zero temporal separation in some frame.
- Events that are **time-like separated** have a guaranteed temporal ordering but no guaranteed spacial ordering. They also have zero spacial separation in some frame, but do not have zero temporal separation in any frame.
- Events that are **light-like separated** have both orderings guaranteed, and have non-zero spacial and temporal separation in all frame.

Now let's apply this understanding to your situation. You have assumed that there exist a single time (in their common reference frame) when the objects have a particular spacial ordering.

Let's call the events marking the location of the objects at that moment (in the selected frame) $A_1$, $B_1$ and $C_1$. Because these happens at a common time in some frame these are necessarily space-like separated. So they have a fixed spacial ordering.

And the same can be said of any group of events that are simultaneous in the selected frame or in the frame of object $A$ after it has accelerated.

To find some events that might not have a unique spacial ordering consider event $A_2$ which occurs a non-trivial time after object $A$ accelerates. If we wait long enough then it will be space like separated from at least event $B_1$ and perhaps event $C_1$ as well.

Comment: Thanks, I think you have a typo in 3rd paragraph: "...space-like separated. So they have a fixed _spatial_ ordering."

Answer (score 3):

No, only the first Lorentz contraction is correct. When A accelerates suddenly to $.97~c$, its position doesn't suddenly change in the frame of B and C. It's still 4 units to the left of B and 8 to the left of C.

Lorentz transformations relate measurements as made in *different frames*. B and C have not changed frames, so it is not appropriate for them to use a Lorentz transformation. A has changed frames, so a Lorentz transformation is appropriate.

You don't use a Lorentz transformation whenever an object accelerates- you use a Lorentz transformation when an *observer* accelerates, or to relate the measurements made by two observers in different frames.

Two observers can, in general, disagree on spatial ordering in certain cases. But B and C are in the same frame, and so share a coordinate system. In this case, they certainly cannot disagree on spatial ordering.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, but why can't I apply the length contraction between $A$ and $B$ to $B$'s frame? Sounds like there a difference whether $A$ moves towards $B$ or $B$ moves towards $A$...

Comment: Length contraction doesn't mean the distance to A, it means the size of A (in 1 dimension).

Comment: @JEB, what about $\gamma$ in Lorentz transforms? Doesn't it contract everything in the spatial dimension?

Comment: @Ferdinand.kraft Lorentz transformations relate measurements as made in *different frames*. B & C have not changed frames, so it is not appropriate for them to use a Lorentz transformation. A has changed frames, so a Lorentz transformation is appropriate. You don't use a Lorentz transformation whenever an object accelerates- you use a Lorentz transformation when an *observer* accelerates, or to relate the measurements made by two observers in different frames.

Comment: @Chris, Thank you. Now consider the following: replace point mass $A$ with a finite size rod $A^\prime$ that accelerates towards $C$. Since $B$ shouldn't apply a lorentz transform, it will not measure any length contraction of the rod. Is this correct?

Comment: @Ferdinand.kraft They (that is, both B and C) will measure a length contraction. That is because in that case they are relating a quantity measured in their frame (the contracted length) to a quantity measured in the rest frame of A (the rest length). Whereas in your original problem they're comparing a distance in their own frame before A accelerates to a distance *still in their own frame* after A accelerates. See how the first one involves two frames and the second one does not?

Comment: @Chris, sorry I still don't get it. If we treat the endpoints of the rod ($A_1$ and $A_2$) as we treated point mass $A$, we would have concluded that the distances $A_1B$ and $A_2B$ are the same as before the rod's acceleration, thus no contraction.

Comment: @Ferdinand.kraft You're reaching a point here where *instantaneous* acceleration is problematic, actually. With an extended object, does "instantaneous" acceleration mean both ends have simultaneous acceleration in the frame of B or in the new rest frame of A? (Remember that simultaneity is not absolute, so those are different things!) The argument you are making assumes the former. In that case, the rod actually *breaks*, as you effectively are forcing it not to Lorentz contract. This is related to [Bell's spaceship paradox](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell%27s_spaceship_paradox).

Comment: @Ferdinand.kraft The usual assumption is that the acceleration is uniform *in A's frame*. Then in B's frame, the back accelerates before the front, and so by the time the whole thing finishes accelerating is shorter.

Comment: @Chris, that's certainly a motivation to work out the math for a finite acceleration over a finite (proper) time interval. It seems that length contraction is due to accumulated acceleration and not simply due to a change of reference frames.

Answer (score 3):

A spacetime diagram might be helpful here.
I've drawn it on rotated graph paper so that we can visualize the ticks along various timelike and spacelike segments.

Instead of 0.97c, I used $v_{Af}=\displaystyle\frac{OC_0}{C_0Z}=\frac{20}{25}=\frac{4}{5}=0.8c$ for convenience. So, $\displaystyle\gamma=\frac{OZ}{C_0Z}=\frac{25}{15}=\frac{5}{3}$.

Note that [from the black segments that are simultaneous to observer-A after observer-A moves] the spatial ordering is preserved up until A's worldline meets B's worldline. So, in the question posed, there is likely some misuse of "length contraction" (which is really about the spatial-separation between two parallel worldlines, e.g. a line parallel to A's worldline after A moves).

[image: Spatial Ordering on Rotated Graph Paper]

Comment: Thanks. Immediately after it starts travelling, $A$ is still at the same distance to $B$ as it were before accelerating, but I'm not sure _why_ you can assume that. Why doesn't $AB$ contracts by 5/3 right after the acceleration?

Comment: Note that worldlines are continuous. So, there's no discontinuous jumps in positions for the observer. However, with a sudden change of velocity, there are discontinuities in the coordinate assignments to distant events. Before event O, A said that B's worldline was 10 space-ticks [sticks] away [using the red spacelike segment perpendicular to A]. After event O, new-A says that B's worldline is 6 sticks away  [using the black spacelike segment perpendicular to new-A] and is decreasing (since A is approaching B).

Answer (score 0):

When A changes frame, it’s now looking at A-B and B-C from that new frame, and they contract when transformed into A’s new frame. B and C remain in their original frame, so there’s no transform, hence A-B and B-C remain the same for them.

Answer (score -1):

Your question is throwing some people off, because you used the words point mass and acceleration. Really, you are considering two distinct point masses whose initial states differ only in their velocities. The inertial reference frames attached to the particles are said to be related by a boost. It is practical to talk about abstract inertial observers instead of concrete point particles located at the origin of inertial frames of reference. It simplifies the language and makes it clear we are only interested in the properties of space-time itself.

Your argument is solid. Accepting the contraction of space due to the Lorentz transformation forces us to conclude that spatial ordering is relative. I really like the setup and notation you have used to demonstrate this. The way you apply special relativity is a little sloppy though. I'll get to that later, but as general advice I would advise you to always reason in terms of events. Events are nice, because in the case of multiple observers it is always clear what is being measured: the event. The observers can simply associate a space-time coordinate to the event, which we can then compare. If we ask multiple observers what the distance between two given observers is, it is not clear at all what we're asking of the observers.

### Answer

The standard approach to resolving the paradox is to remember that simultaneity is relative, draw a space-time diagram and show that everything is good and well. I'm already boring myself, so let's try something different.

One of the central themes of special relativity is that space and time stand on equal footing. For every spatial concept, there is a corresponding temporal concept. We have space contraction and time dilation, energy and momentum, density and flux and so on. You have created a spatial paradox. What is the corresponding temporal paradox? I'd like to use your notation, but I'm going to refine your argument a little bit.

Consider three inertial observers, $A,B$ and $C$. Observers $B$ and $C$ are at
rest with respect to each other and $A$ is not. $A$ observes that $B$ and $C$ are moving towards him and he measures that $B$ passes him (an event) after one unit of time passed on his clock and after having travelled one unit of distance relative to $B$. He passes $C$ after two units of time and two units of distance. In your notation, slightly adapted, the space diagrams are

$$A:A-B-C$$ 
$$B:A-B\ \ |\ \ C$$
$$C:B\ \ |\ \ A--C$$

The vertical bar represent an infinite amount of dashes. From $B$'s perspective, for example, the distance he travels before he meets $C$ is infinite, because they never actually meet. I am forced to flip $A$ and $B$ in the third diagram, because it is impossible to fit an infinite distance ($B\ |\ C$) within a finite distance ($A--C$). Observers $B$ and $C$ disagree. According to $B$, at the beginning of the scenario $A$ is to the left of $B$. $C$ says $A$ starts off at the right of $B$. This is your spatial paradox, slightly reformulated.

The corresponding time diagrams are exactly the same as the space diagrams. The dashes now represent the time intervals that are recorded by the observers. $B$ and $C$ are once again saying something very different. According to $B$, it will meet $A$ in the future. $C$ says $B$ has already met $A$. This is the temporal paradox.

In summary, the scenario starts out as follows. According to $B$, $A$ is on the left of $B$ and will pass $B$ in the future. According to $C$, $A$ is on the right of $B$ and has passed $B$ in the past. These two statements do not contradict each other at all. We see that the spatial paradox has a temporal twin and that they resolve mutually.

Wouldn't it be neat if other paradoxes in special relativity worked like this?

Comment: "From B's perspective, for example, the distance he travels before he meets C is infinite, because they never actually meet." From B's perspective, the distance he travels is always zero, because from B's perspective B isn't moving.

Comment: I should at the very least say "with respect to A". I'll recheck the argument tomorrow to see if there other flaws. I hope you'll agree the basic idea of paradox pairs still holds, because that's my reason for doing it this way.

Comment: B and C are in the same reference frame, and so share the same notion of simultaneity. They cannot disagree on the time or spatial ordering of any two events. The source of your mistake seems to be the odd definition of "distance" you're using. B and C are still a finite distance away from one another in every reference frame, even if they never meet. Just like no one would suggest that we're an infinite distance apart from each other, even though we will (more than likely) never meet.

Comment: As for "paradox pairs," I don't really agree. The physics is symmetrical between time and space, but human intuition is not. Many of the "paradoxes" involving time in special relativity become "well, obviously *that's* true" when restated in terms of space.

Comment: @vosov, sorry your answer is hard to understand.